# Как получить список всех символических ссылок?

Tags: unix, shell

Требуется получить список всех символических ссылок в каталоге, игнорируя некоторые подкаталоги.

Пробовал так:

```
find -L ./ -xtype l ! -path "./proc/*" ! -path "./sys/*" ! -path "./dev/*" 2> /dev/null
```

но выводит не все символические ссылки, а только те, что в каталоге etc/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

поиск «мягких» ссылок (symlinks) в текущем каталоге и во всех подкаталогах рекурсивно:

```
$ find -type l
```

если надо исключить каталог, например, `proc`, в текущем каталоге, то:

```
$ find -type l ! -path `./proc/*`
```

---

понятно, что все каталоги должны иметь атрибуты `r` и `x` для текущего пользователя.